# Decoding a special character in C#

Tags: c#, html

I am wondering how I could decode the special character `â€¢` to HTML?

I have tried using `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but not luck yet.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is not HTML decoding, but rather that the text was encoded in one character set (e.g., windows-1252) and then encoded again as a second (UTF-8).

In UTF-8, `•` is decoded as `E2 80 A2`. When this byte sequence is read using windows-1252 encoding, `E2 80 A2` encodes as `â€¢`.  (Saved again as UTF-8 `â€¢` becomes `C3 A2 E2 82 AC C2 A2 20 54 65 73 74`.)

If the file is a windows-1252-encoded file, the file can simply be read with the correct encoding (e.g., as an argument to a StreamReader constructor.):

```
new StreamReader(..., Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
```

If the file was saved with an incorrect encoding, the encoding can be reversed in some cases.  For instance, for the string sequence in your question, you can write:

```
string s = "â€¢"; // the string sequence that is not properly encoded
var b = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(s); // b = `E2 80 A2`
string c = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);  // c = `•`
```

Note that many common nonprinting characters are in the range `U+2000` to `U+2044` ([Reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/2000-2FFF)), such as "smart quotes", bullets, and dashes.  Thus, the sequence `â€?`, where `?` is any character, will typically signify this type of encoding error.  This allows this type of error to be corrected more broadly:

```
static string CorrectText(string input)
{
    var winencoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
    return Regex.Replace(input, "â€.",
        m => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(winencoding.GetBytes(m.Value)));
}
```

Calling this function with text malformed in this way will correct some (but not all) errors.  For instance `CorrectText("â€¢Testâ€“orâ€œ")` will return the intended `•Test–or“`.

Answer (score 2):

HtmlDecode is for converting Html-encoded strings into a readable string format. Perhaps `HtmlEncode` might be what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I think OP wants to see `•` instead of `â€¢`

Comment: Ah yes.. it says *character* not characters.

Comment: How does `â€¢` translate to `•` though? The html representation of the bullet point is `&bull;` - or am I missing something?