# Handling special characters

Tags: c#, encoding

I am wondering how to best handle a special character such as â€™ using c#?

e.g

```
public static string DecodeFrom64(string toDecode)
{
   byte[] arrayToDecode = System.Convert.FromBase64String(toDecode);
   return  System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arrayToDecode);
}
```

Comment: What are you using it for?

Comment: The description(string) from db contains some special characters which needs decoding for read on front end.

Comment: You haven't explained what problems you're having with these characters.  How are the Base64 strings you are decoding being generated?  What output are you seeing that isn't what you expect?

Comment: What is your front end? A web app? If it is a web app how are you displaying it?

Comment: Are you sure your about Unicode? Maybe UTF-8 ?

Comment: You appear to be confused about how things like Unicode and UTF-8 interact.  Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16577994/920669) to one of your earlier questions (and mark it as the correct answer, since it really is).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've stored a `UTF-8` string to a different encoding in your database - probably the `Windows-1252` code page (`CP2152`).  As a result the `UTF-8` character `’` represented by the byte sequence `E2 80 99` is translated into the `CP2152` single-byte characters `â€™`.  This was all explained to your previously in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577994/920669), which also gives a solution to your current problem.

In order to get back to the original `UTF-8` encoding you will need to take the string returned from your database and correct it with the following code:

```
public static string UTF8From1252(string source)
{
    // get original UTF-8 bytes from CP1252-encoded string
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(source);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

This highlights the fact that it is vital to use the correct encoding at all times when using the `GetBytes` method.

It is important to note that the reverse of this transformation is not always possible, since there are gaps in the `CP2152` code space - values that will be discarded or altered during conversion from byte values.

The hex values for these gaps are: `81 8D 8F 90 9D`.

Unfortunately these values are present in various `UTF-8` encodings, such as `”` (`E2 80 9D`).  If you have one of these values in your database then it will not load correctly.  Depending on how you did the first stage conversion the third byte may be lost or corrupted in the database, in which case you cannot retrieve it.